# How to return single value from anonymous Linq.Expressions.Expression

Tags: c#, linq

When using Entity Framework with LINQ I can code like: 
`var a = context.Employee.Where(x => x.Name.Equals("Michael")).FirstOrDefault();` 
I'm curious how to create custom method with anonymous linq expression.
I have a model class and method as follow

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

static T Single<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class
{
    //This is from the database
    List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>
    {
        new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "Michael" },
        new Employee { Id = 2, Name = "Derek" }
    };

    //I have no idea how to return single value of employees

    //var expression = (BinaryExpression)predicate.Body;
    //var left = expression.Left.Type.Name;
    //Func<T, bool> func = predicate.Compile();
    //T value = method(html.ViewData.Model);
    //T t = (T)Convert.ChangeType(a, typeof(T));
    //Employee emp = (Employee)Convert.ChangeType(t, typeof(Employee));

    //var body = predicate.Body;

    //var prop = (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)predicate.Body).Member;
    //var propValue = prop.GetValue(func, null);

    //var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    //var property = Expression.Property(parameter, expression.Member.Name);
    //var equal = Expression.Equal(property, Expression.Constant(propValue));
    //var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equal, parameter);


    return null;
}
```

Calling the above method should be like

```
Employee emp = Single<Employee>(d => d.Name == "Michael");
```

Comment: have you tried `AsQuerable().Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault`?

Comment: @Valentin No, I won't. I want custom method.

Answer (score 0):

You can call FirstOrDefault directly

```
var a = context.Employee.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals("Michael"));
```

Or inside your function you can use

```
return employees.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
```

Comment: No. I want to create my own generic custom method.

Comment: Use this inside your Single method
     return employees.FirstOrDefault(predicate);

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `IQuerable.Where` instead of `IEnumerable.Where` 
First one uses `Expression<Func<TSource, Boolean>>` as parameter. Second uses `Func<TSource, Boolean>`.

So you need to use `AsQuerable()` and then `Where()` 
So in your case it should look like

```
return employees.AsQuerable().Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault()
```

If you want to pass `delegate` instead of `Expression` you need to change method to `static T Single<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : class` and then 
`return employees.FirstOrDefault(predicate)`

So you can use it this way

`Employee emp = Single<Employee>(d => d.Name == "Michael");`

Comment: I know that. But that's not custom method of my own.

Comment: As I said, I want my own generic custom method. All I want is how to get single value from anonymous Linq.Expressions.Expression. I know what you mean but it's not what I want

Comment: @derodevil what do you mean by `single value from anonymous Linq.Expressions.Expression`?

Comment: T is anonymous type. This can be anything. I have list of objects in various type and I want to create a custom generic method that returns single object taken from the list of object in exact type. Your answer is correct if I'm using Entity Framework.

Comment: @derodevil why do you think `Your answer is correct if I'm using Entity Framework.`?